# creating a shiny plotly using an RDS data

Tags: r, graph, shiny, plotly

I'm a math student studying data science.
I'm trying to take the user's decision of which columns to use for the graph(plotly), unfortunately, the graph is blank.

I would like the graph a scatter or line plot to show date vs nbrskieur as a default and be able to change either x, y, or both according to the user's preference.
I have not been able to find any tutorials or answers on how to plot with user-chosen columns from an RDS.

help would be much appreciated, thank you

````
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

# Define UI for the application that draws a plotly from RDS data
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("ploting RDS data"),
    
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Input: Select a file ----
            fileInput("file1", "Choose rds File",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = ".rds"),
            selectInput("var1","select the x variable from the file", choices = c("Date","jour","report","noubre de skieur","ndemj", "nbrtotal")),
            selectInput("var2","select the y variable from the file", choices = c("Date","jour","report","noubre de skieur","ndemj", "nbrtotal")),
            ),
        
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("skieurdist")
        )
        
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a plotly with default columns of dates and nbrskieur(number of skiers)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$skieurdist <- renderPlotly({
        tbl_rds <- readRDS(input$file1$datapath)
        plot.obj <<-list()
        plot.obj$tbl_rds <<- tbl_rds
        xcol <- as.numeric(input$var1)
        ycol <- as.numeric(input$var2)
        #p <- plot_ly(plot.obj$table_rds, x = input$var2, y = ycol, type = "scatter")
        skieur <- plot_ly(plot.obj$tbl_rds, x = xcol, y = ycol, type = "bar")
        # p %>%  layout(legend = list(x = 1, y = 0.5 , bgcolor = "#E2E2E2"))
        #require(input$submit)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
[here is some example of the data that I have][1]```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcZsP.png
````